# How to expand ExtJS SplitButton?

Tags: javascript, extjs, controls

How to expand ExtJS SplitButton, to see sub items, from code?

Ext version 3.1.0

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try the showMenu() method to display the menu items.

```
sptButt.showMenu();
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example how to open context menu by clicking on a split button:

```
{
    xtype: 'splitbutton',
    text: 'This is a split button, no kidding',
    handler: function () {
        this.showMenu();
    }
}
```